# Badge count experiencing cropping at 7 digits

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

If you have 7 digits of badges on Programmers.SE, you start to experience truncation:

> [image: seven digits]

With 8 digits of badges, you really get chopped off:

> [image: Robert's got more than 31 bronze]

This isn't a problem on other Stack Exchange sites:

> [image]

Yea, we've got [big balls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJ3tqIukBKg) for our badges, but there might be some adjustments that can be done to pull in the space so that the current badge distribution is handled (it will be awhile before anyone gets 100 gold or 1000 bronze).

Comment: reproduced this with FF 30.0 at Windoze 7 at this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/251352/31260

Answer (score 1):

Made the badge CSS slightly narrower and reduced the padding.

You should be able to see your badges in all their glory in the next build.